# How can I create an animation like WhatsApp archive button spawn animation with SwiftUI on watchOS?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mobile, watchkit, watchos

```
List {
    //I Want This Button To Appear When User Over Scroll To Top
    Button(action: { ... }, label: {
        Text("Archive")
    })
    
    ForEach(0..<5) { item in
        ChatButton()
    }
    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
    .listRowPlatterColor(.clear)
    
    Rectangle()
        .frame(width: Sizes.width - 8, height: Sizes.h2)
        .foregroundColor(Color("Background"))
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        .listRowPlatterColor(.clear)
    
    CenteredTextButton(
        text: "Durumlar", textColor: Color("White"),
        isLink: true, destinationKey: "statuses", buttonAction: {}
    )
    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
    .listRowPlatterColor(.clear)
    
}
```

In the above code, I want the Button that says Archive to appear when user scrolls to top when user already at the top (ex: on negative offset y)

[image: image description]